# Form Autofill is not working with JSF Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, jsf, autofill

As soon as I change my submit button to an Ajax request, autofilling of forms won't work anymore.

The following snippet works fine with Chrome and Firefox:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText />
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

For example if I enter "test", then "test" will be proposed the next time I use the field.
If I change the request to Ajax, then autofilling will not work.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText />
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit">
        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with ajax?

Comment: Try assigning an explicit id to both the form and the inputText. Does that make a difference? (would not expect it to make a difference, but just to be sure)

Comment: I tried assigning an explicit id. but it has no effect. The JSF-generated id is stable in my case anyways. so it does not make a difference. The same applies for the name, which is also auto-generated in JSF and which is the target for autofill in most Browsers. There must be some difference in how ajax requests behave with the autofill feature, whether it is on the browser side or in the request itself.

Comment: The autofill is a pure client related thing. And the `h:inputText` (and the form) have no knowledge about the ajax part of the button. Compare the client-side generated html and look for differences. And if it fails both in chrome and firefox and you use those in tags you sort of implicitly state it works e.g. in IE or Safari. So those tags are sort of irrelevant I think.

Comment: The ajax-Button executes the request via "onClick"-javascript. I guess, by this, the browser is not storing the value. It might be a general browser or JSF problem.

Comment: Not related imo. Autofill happens before the submit. And it works here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml check if adding a `value=` makes a difference (not having a value is a weird design anyway)

Comment: The primefaces showcase works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In my application I have values of course. But for the example it doesn't make a difference. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Then try to find out using a searchengine what the differences between firefox and chrome in general regarding autocomplete for plain html.

Comment: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/ (next time please pay a little more attention to investigate/narrow down things. upfront before posting ;-), or does your example not work in Firefox?